# I want to pass array data from Swift to Metal's fragment shader in Uniform

Tags: swift, metal

I am trying to pass array data in Uniform from Swift to Metal's fragment shader. I am able to pass normal Float numbers that are not arrays with no problem.

The structure is as follows

// Swift

```
struct Uniforms {
    var test: [Float]
}
```

The values are as follows

```
let floatArray: [Float] = [0.5]
```

As usual, we are going to write and pass the following As mentioned above, normal Float values can be passed without any problem.

```
commandEncoder.setFragmentBytes(&uniforms, length: MemoryLayout<Uniforms>.stride, index: 0)
```

The shader side should be as follows

// Metal Shader

```
struct Uniforms {
    float test[1];
};

// Fragment Shader

// in fragment shader
float testColor = 1.0;
 // for statement
for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
    testColor *= uniforms.test[i];
}

float a = 1.0 - testColor;

return float4(1.0,0.0,0.0,a);
```

I thought that 0.5 in the array was passed, but no value is passed. I think I am writing something wrong, but how should I write it?

Answer (score 0):

The code you wrote does not make any sense

```
struct Uniforms {
    var test: [Float]
}
```

Uniforms is a swift struct here, which if you look at it in memory will contain a struct that's part of the implementation of the `Array`. So when you take a pointer to `uniforms`, you are not seeing your float, you are seeing internal bits of an `Array`.

What you need is to define a C-struct that looks like

```
struct Uniforms {
    float test[1];
};
```

and then you include this bridging header in your shader code and also use it as bridging header in Swift.

There's an article about how to set up bridging header: [Importing Objective-C into Swift](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/importing-objective-c-into-swift). Doesn't matter that it says Objective-C. You can use only C in the bridging header and it will be fine.

In turn, Swift will produce a Swift interface for the struct.

Then you can fill out that struct and pass it to Metal using `set*Bytes` functions or put the struct into an `MTLBuffer` and pass it that way.

Comment: Thanks. As above, this part is included in the shader. `struct Uniforms {
    float test[1];
};`I guess I wrote `//uniform` as set*Bytes, in `commandEncoder.setFragmentBytes(&uniforms, length: MemoryLayout<Uniforms>.stride, index: 0)` Is this a problem? If it's not an array, I haven't had any problems so far.

Comment: It has to be the same struct in Swift, not a struct with a swift array. That's a completely different thing.

Comment: If the structure is wrong, how should it be written?

Comment: It should be written in C and imported into Swift through bridging headers, just as I described in the answer. That's the onyl way to be sure that the structs are layout compatible.

Comment: The one in C is the one written in the Metal shader, and the one on the Swift side is as above,
`struct Uniforms {
    var test: [Float]
}`.
as described above. I think that is written in the question. I have been using this part for passing normal Float values in Uniforms since before I started working with arrays. I don't see a problem with that part; I feel like there are more problems with MTLBuffer and such, such as whether arrays have to be sent with MTLBuffer and such.

Comment: Okay, I just told you that having separate structs in C and in Swift will not always work. It has to be the same struct. If you are asking why it does not work, the answer is because those are completely different structs. When you are using pod types there’s a chance that layouts will match. But there’s no guarantee

Comment: What is the correct way to write the structure on the C side of Metal's shader in this case?

Comment: It’s in the answer that you are commenting on.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/importing-objective-c-into-swift